# How to get logs about affected objects by S3 Multi-Object Delete

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudtrail

S3 provides two ways to delete objects: A [DELETE operation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectDELETE.html) for deleting single objects and a [Multi-Object Delete operation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/multiobjectdeleteapi.html) to delete multiple objects with a single API call.

For the DELETE operation [S3 access logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html) and [CloudTrail S3 data logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudtrail-logging.html#cloudtrail-object-level-tracking) contain information about the affected object. That's not the case for Multi-Object Delete operations, which are just a POST request, containing the affected objects in its body, which is logged neither by S3 access logs nor by CloudTrail S3 data logs.

What's the best way to keep track of which objects were affected by a Multi-Object Delete operation?

Comment: That is a good question, thank you. I hope that there is an answer besides "not possible".